# AudioRecord not recording anything

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to record audio on my Android device using the `AudioRecord` class. But the data that I read from it when I stop recording is all zeroes. When I start recording audio I do:

```
int BufferElements2Rec = 1024;
int BytesPerElement = 2;

recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic,
                           8000,
                           ChannelIn.Mono,
                           Encoding.Pcm16bit,
                           BufferElements2Rec * BytesPerElement);

recorder.StartRecording();
```

And when I stop recording:

```
var sData = new short[BufferElements2Rec];
recorder.Read(sData, 0, BufferElements2Rec);

if (sData.Any(d => d != 0))
{
    int test = 1; // Breakpoint never gets hit
}

recorder.Stop();
recorder.Release();
recorder.Dispose();
recorder = null;
```

Any idea why?

**EDIT**

I just realized that even after calling `recorder.StartRecording()` the `RecordingState` property is still `Stopped`

Comment: Share your device detail, please

Comment: Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manifest.xml

Add this line to Mainfest File for Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

and Give Microphone Permission from,

```
Settings > Apps > YOUR_APP_NAME > Permissions
```

Record your Audio after giving `Permissions` for `Microphone`.

Comment: I already did this. But I fixed it by uninstalling the app from my phone and reinstalling it. I read somewhere that it is essential to call `recorder.Release()` or it won't be available again, not sure if that had anything to do with it...